# c# write text box to txt file, how to name file?

Tags: c#

How do I rename the name of the text file according to a text box? I did Google it but could not find any answers, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

The code is as followed;

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Notes\Notes.txt", txtbox);
```

What I want to do is rename the `"Notes.txt"` to whatever is in `richtextBox1` and to have `.txt` automatically added on to the end of it.

Thanks and sorry is this is a really stupid question, but I couldn't find any answers online

Comment: Well, do you know how to get the contents of `richtextBox1` as a string? If it's just going to contain a filename, why would it be a RichTextBox? (I'm guessing it is, based on the name...) What would it mean to have a filename in italics, or in red?

Comment: Instead of renaming, why not write to a file with the desired name to begin with?

Comment: Your Title, text and code snippet do not match at all. Do you want to rename a file? Do you want to append something to a file? Do you know how to get the contents of a textbox as string? Contents of RichtextBox as a string? What should go where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Notes\" + richtextbox1.Text + ".txt", txtbox);
```

Would that work?

Comment: if richtextbox1 is indeed a RTF text box it will contain RichText, wich does not work as a filename